# Using PHP to append JSON file with new MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm working on reading the information in a database into a JSON file. The code I have reads to the file fine but what I'm looking for is a way to only append the new data not present in the file already. Every time I run my code it adds all of the information stored in the database each time.

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '') or die('Error connecting to server');

mysql_select_db('twitter', $con); 

$file = 'file.json';

$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM sample_data');

//Define columns 
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Username', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Retweet_count', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Origin', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Destination', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Text', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Sentiment_type', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Sentiment_score', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Profile_picture', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'TweetID', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $temp = array();
    // each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Username']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Retweet_count']); // typecast all numbers to the appropriate type (int or float) as needed - otherwise they are input as strings
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Origin']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Destination']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Text']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Sentiment_type']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (double) $r['Sentiment_score']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Profile_picture']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['TweetID']);

    // insert the temp array into $rows
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// populate the table with rows of data
$table['rows'] = $rows;

file_put_contents($file, json_encode($table, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

// Read it back out with
echo file_get_contents($file);


// set up header; first two prevent IE from caching queries
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you add a column to the database marking it to true if the data has already been exported and then changing select to only get false items?

Comment: @ObieMD5 suggest is a good one. But, why does it need to be appended? Can you not just wipe the data each time?

Comment: You can also `json_decode` the file, determine which is the last record, then adjust your query to retrieve entries past that last element.

Comment: @jakenoble: there may be thousands of records which may cause too much overhead to re-do it over and over. An "incremental export" is beneficial in a lot of scenarios.

Comment: @BradChristie a fair point

Comment: That is why you mark ones that have already been exported in the column and you now have incremental exports

Answer (score 0):

You can't just "append" new data to a json string, that generally destroys the json by introducing syntax errors. Remember that the json string HAS to be syntactically valid javascript.

So if your json string starts out as

```
['a','b','c'];
```

and you tack on a couple new array elements, you'll end up with

```
['a','b','c']['d',e'];
```

and get garbage because that's not valid json/javascript.

You need to **DECODE** the json back to a native PHP structure, do your appending there, then RE-ENCODE to json:

```
$json = '....';
$array = json_decode($json);

while( ... ) {
  $array[] = $new_data;
}
$json = json_encode($array);
```